# Series object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

When i am calling a function using apply function and store into one variable that variable will become series. When merging those variable it says `Series object has no attribute 'merge'` After that have converted into dataframe and got unhashable type: 'DataFrame' error.
i want to merge those df's.

Code which i am running:

```
def src_aggregated_input(columnname, tablename):
    try:
        df_src1["column_name"] = df_src1["column_name"].replace('', np.nan, regex=True)
        if df_src1["column_name"].isnull().values.any():
            df_agg_src = pd.DataFrame(columns=['src_agg_cnt'])
            return df_agg_src
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(' + columnname + ') AS src_agg_cnt,' + columnname + ' FROM ' + \
              tablename + ' group by ' + columnname
        #sql = sql[0]
        loging(datetime.datetime.now(), '-agg src sql', sql)
        df_agg_src = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db_conn)
        print("df_agg_src",df_agg_src)
        print("src",type(df_agg_src))
        return df_agg_src

    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        loging(datetime.datetime.now(), 'src_agg', sys.exc_info()[1])
        return np.nan
```

**Above function output:**

```
df_agg_src       src_agg_cnt  Acct_id
0               2  DAI0001
1               2  DAI0002
2               2  DAI0003
3               2  DAI0004
4               2  DAI0005
...           ...      ...
996             1  DAI0997
997             1  DAI0998
998             1  DAI0999
999             2  DAI1000
1000            1  DAI1001

[1001 rows x 2 columns]
src <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
df_agg_src    src_agg_cnt cust_code
0            1      C001
1            2      C003
2            1      C012
3            1      C345
4            2      C234
5            1      C743
6            1      C456
src <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

**df_src1 dataframe output:**

```
df_src1       table_name column_name 
0  banking_fraud     Acct_id         
1      sale_mast   cust_code
```

**Function call:**

```
df_src2 = df_src1.apply(lambda x: src_aggregated_input(x['column_name'], x['schema_table']), axis=1)#series error

#Convert to dataframe
df_src2 = df_src1.apply(lambda x: src_aggregated_input(x['column_name'], x['schema_table']), axis=1).to_frame() #output/type of src_aggregated_input function is dataframe

def aggregated_cnt_check():
    try:
        df_agg_merge = df_src2.merge(df_tgt2,   #error in merging part
                                   indicator=True, 
                                   how='outer')
        return df_agg_diff
```

output of df_src2:

```
type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
**df_src2**                                                    0
0        src_agg_cnt  Acct_id
0               2  ...
1     src_agg_cnt cust_code
0            1      C...
```

Please suggest how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example of your data?

Comment: Hi Alia, you should provide an example of your df and most important the function `src_aggregated_input`

Comment: Hi @imburningbabe/ @Serge de Gosson de Varennes, have provided other requested information.